# git modified content error during git commit

Tags: git, commit

## Update -1

This is what i am trying to do.

```
cd /tmp
git clone http://git.example.com/foo/openstack.git -b ansible-roles ansible-roles-new
cd ansible-roles-new
cp -r /etc/ansible/roles /tmp/ansible-roles-new
```

After that i did `git commit -m "foo..."` and ran `git status` but it was showing `modified content` not sure why and not letting me `git push` :(

This is my directory structure inside `ansible-roles-new folder`

```
[root@foo ansible-roles-new]# ls -l /tmp/ansible-roles-new/roles/
total 196
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:43 ansible-hardening
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:43 apt_package_pinning
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  203 Jun 24 22:45 bird
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:45 os_cinder
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:43 ceph_client
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:43 config_template
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  219 Jun 24 22:45 etcd
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:43 galera_client
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Jun 24 22:43 galera_server
...
...
...
many more...
```

This is very strange stuff going on.

```
[root@foo ansible-roles-new]# git status
# On branch ansible-roles
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   roles/os_cinder (modified content)
#   modified:   roles/os_keystone (modified content)
#   modified:   roles/os_magnum (modified content)
#   modified:   roles/os_octavia (modified content)
#   modified:   roles/rabbitmq_server (modified content)
#   modified:   roles/rsyslog_client (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So this is what i did, as per googling, it seems when i copy roles dir it already had some `.git` file in it, so i did clean up like following.

```
[root@foo ansible-roles-new]# rm -rf roles/os_cinder/.git*
```

did git init

```
[root@foo ansible-roles-new]# git init
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /tmp/ansible-roles-new/.git/
```

but it didn't created .git dir again, also look like its not tracking that directory anymore.

Am i missing anything?

running `git-1.8.x`

## EDIT:

if i modify anything in `roles/os_cinder` dir its not tracking anymore and not detecting any changes.

`git diff` saying it's dirty but not sure where?

```
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit ff5207066cfef8eb380c35d398a884d357e2738d
+Subproject commit ff5207066cfef8eb380c35d398a884d357e2738d-dirty
diff --git a/ansible-roles-new/roles/os_cinder b/etc-ansible/roles/os_cinder
--- a/ansible-roles-new/roles/os_cinder
+++ b/ansible-roles-new/roles/os_cinder
@@ -1 +1 @@
```

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is. You executed `git status` in one folder, removed a `.git` folder *in a **different** folder* , then executed `git init` in the first folder again. You're missing an explanation of what the problem is and what you hoped to accomplish with those commands. Why did you execute them? What was the problem?

Comment: where you seeing i am changing folder, i am always inside in `/tmp/ansible-roles-new/` directory and inside that directory i have `roles` dir `/tmp/ansible-roles-new/roles/`

Comment: But you did `rm -rf roles/os_cinder/.git`, that is not the `.git` folder that `git status` will be using in the first example. The `.git` folder in the first example has to be in the current folder or higher up the folder hierarchy, not deeper into the hierarchy where you delete a folder in the second piece of code. As is evident from that last output, the `.git` folder is in the `ansible-roles-new` folder, but you removed a different folder.

Comment: i have edit question anyway if you think that is confusing, totally agreed with you but if you see my error mesg `modified content` if i remove `.git` from sub folder like `rm -rf roles/os_cinder/.git*` my `git status` command showing no error for that specific directory but it stopped tracking that folder after that.

Comment: The confusing part is that I still don't know why you have a problem. You say "This is very strange stuff going on". Can you explain what the strange stuff is? **Why** are you asking a question, what is the problem?

Comment: I have modified my question, check it out.. all i am doing adding `roles` folder to track via git and i copy that folder in my one of git branch but its throwing that `modified content` error and not letting me push anything

Comment: You have set these up as *submodules*, where you have a top-level repository that has little or no content and merely serves as a place to keep track of hash IDs from each of its submodules. Each submodule is an ordinary Git repository. What you do in the superproject is keep track of *which commit hash* to use in each of the submodule Git repositories.

Comment: I don't know what is `submodules` but i think my problem is when i download ansible roles from public `github` in `/etc/ansible/roles` directory that had already some `.git` stuff which driving this issue nuts when i am trying to move those folder in my company git server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i found. when i checkout ansible/roles from public `github.com` repo it has already some `.git` ancher. and later when i was trying to move same folder in my internal git server that was causing above issue.

After cleaning up all `.git` it works.

```
for qw in `ls /etc/ansible/roles`; do  rm -rf /etc/ansible/roles/$qw/.git*; done
```